# The inception_v1 model does not conform to the paper

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am reading the code of GoogLeNet inception_v1 model [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/nets/inception_v1.py). If I understand it correctly, 5x5 convolution is included in the inception structure. But the 5x5 convolution is replaced by 3x3 convolution everywhere in the model. For example:

```
 end_point = 'Mixed_3b'
 with tf.variable_scope(end_point):
     with tf.variable_scope('Branch_0'):
         branch_0 = slim.conv2d(net, 64, [1, 1], scope='Conv2d_0a_1x1')
     with tf.variable_scope('Branch_1'):
         branch_1 = slim.conv2d(net, 96, [1, 1], scope='Conv2d_0a_1x1')
         branch_1 = slim.conv2d(branch_1, 128, [3, 3], scope='Conv2d_0b_3x3')
     with tf.variable_scope('Branch_2'):
         branch_2 = slim.conv2d(net, 16, [1, 1], scope='Conv2d_0a_1x1')
         branch_2 = slim.conv2d(branch_2, 32, [3, 3], scope='Conv2d_0b_3x3')
     with tf.variable_scope('Branch_3'):
         branch_3 = slim.max_pool2d(net, [3, 3], scope='MaxPool_0a_3x3')
         branch_3 = slim.conv2d(branch_3, 32, [1, 1], scope='Conv2d_0b_1x1')
     net = tf.concat(axis=3, values=[branch_0, branch_1, branch_2, branch_3])
 end_points[end_point] = net
 if final_endpoint == end_point: return net, end_points
```

where I think the `branch_2` should be like this:

```
with tf.variable_scope('Branch_2'):
     branch_2 = slim.conv2d(net, 16, [1, 1], scope='Conv2d_0a_1x1')
     branch_2 = slim.conv2d(branch_2, 32, [5, 5], scope='Conv2d_0b_5x5')
```

I do not believe the author would make such an obvious mistake, so could somebody tell me the reason or I just have a wrong understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in the published repo - see https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/443. The published snapshot actually contains 5x5 convs. Having 3x3 convolutions instead of 5x5 convolutions makes no sense there (then two branches of the inception network would be structurally the same).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Glad that someone already noticed this.